# How can a logarithmic equation be represented by the corresponding parameters a and b?

Tags: equation-solving

The known conditions are:

```
Log[14, 7] == a, 14^b == 5
```

How can the parameters a and b be used to represent the value of this logarithmic equation?

```
Log[35, 28]
```

The process of manual calculation is as follows:

[image]

```
In[16]:= Reduce[{Log[14, 7] == a, 14^b == 5, t == Log[35, 28]}, t]

Out[16]= 
a == Log[7]/(Log[2] + Log[7]) && 14^b == 5 && 
 t == (2 Log[2] + Log[7])/(Log[5] + Log[7])
```

The above code calculation cannot use two parameters, a and b, to represent the logarithmic size?